# Bamboo display jacoco reports

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, bamboo, jacoco

I am able to generate jacoco reports in my Android project locally. When I run the task on Bamboo, it works as well. Now I would like to display the coverage results in the task, is it possible? I saw posts and question using SonarQube, but it seems like a lot of work for something so trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach report as an artifact of build - see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-9179

Comment: it works, I managed to display nice reports using `location=app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestProdReleaseUnitTestReport/html` and `copy pattern=**/*.*`